# vuejs, issue with delete on reorder element

Tags: vue.js

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/niladri_developer/z7030j01

```
remove: function(item) {
    var self = this;
    var list = this.list;
       
    index=  list.indexOf(item);
        
    console.log(index);
        
    list.splice(index,1);

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.list));
    this.$set('list',list);
}
```

I drag an element on 2nd box in the following order: 2nd, 3rd and 1st

Then I click on delete of the 2nd box and get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at before (vue.js:1163:12)
    at Fragment.singleBefore [as before] (vue.js:4464:5)
    at Directive.move (vue.js:4994:12)
    at Directive.diff (vue.js:4831:18)
    at Directive.update (vue.js:4724:12)
    at VueComponent._update (vue.js:7713:17)
    at Watcher.run (vue.js:3273:19)
    at runBatcherQueue (vue.js:3006:15)
    at Array.flushBatcherQueue (vue.js:2980:5)
    at MutationObserver.nextTickHandler (vue.js:434:18)
```

Why it causes issue on delete? But there is no issue on delete on box 1?

Comment: What's the issue?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hello , if u drag it from box1 to box2 , and drag it like 3 ,2 , 1 and remove 2 . u saw error on console .  but if i drag it like 1,2,3 and remove like 1,2,3 its ok , but if i remove in a random order it shows error . As I indexOf find the position and splice it . Can u find a solution that can remove it in a random order on a dragged box . i dont find any issue on Parent box . But issue started when i move to dragged one and do random remove

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors as I drag boxes around and randomly delete them.  Everything is working fine.  Unless you can give us details of the exact error you're getting and how to reproduce the error, it's going to be difficult for someone to help you.

Comment: suppose i drag items like this    3 , 2, 1  --> and i remove 2 that is in middle  : now i got this error on console   --> vue.js:1163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Comment: i got to know that as my this.list is component property . if i reset like this           this.$set('list',JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(this.list)));
but it will take those element into container 1 !! so need to know How could i delete a component data in a random order on a dragged List